# Тригонометрические функции .net framework

Tags: c#, visual-basic

Есть статический класс *Math*. Есть в нем тригонометрические функции. Возьмем *Cos* и *Acos*. Наверное, я забыл тригонометрию, потому что ожидаю что эта строка `Console.WriteLine(Math.Acos(Math.Cos(ang)));` выведет мне значение *ang*, а она выводит непонятные вещи. Объясните почему?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вероятно, вы забыли, что тригонометрические функции в C# принимают угол не в градусах, а в радианах.
Сначала вам надо аргумент функции Cos сконвертировать в радианы:

```
double rad = ang *(Math.PI / 180.0);

а затем уже провести обратное преобразование в градусы для результата функции Acos: 

Console.WriteLine(Math.Acos(Math.Cos(rad))*(180.0 /Math.PI));
```

[Пример](http://ideone.com/u4YY8J)

Comment: Если ввожу 190, получаю в ответе 170. Хотелось бы в этом случае получать -170. Короче есть долгота от -180 до 180. Нужен способ преобразовать переданный угол в угол этого диапазона.

Comment: @iRumba, твоё преобразование верно для углов от 0 до 180 градусов. При помощи sin можно получить от -90 до +90. Но углы от -180 до -90 не получить тригонометрическими функциями никак. А чем не угодил способ посчитать остатки от деления?

Comment: (ang % 360) - 180 ?

Comment: мешает то, что зависимость круговая. Не смог придумать формулу

Comment: тут получается, что начальная величина 0. От нее движемся на увеличение до 180. Далее начинается убывание, но с отрицательным углом. ****** 179, 180(-180), -179, -178, *******

Answer (score 1):

Это преобразование не совсем обратимо. В соответствии с тригонометрическими правилами исходный угол будет получаться только для аргументов от 0 до PI.

Впрочем, там всё равно баг есть: `Math.Cos(1e27)`.

Comment: Ну мне как раз такое преобразование и нужно, чтобы преобразовать угол в 480 градусов к нужному значению. Так что все норм. А что означает ваш пример? Что за баг?

Comment: @iRumba, баг в том, что начиная с некоторого значения Cos и Sin возвращают свой аргумент, что заведомо неверно, поскольку Значение этих функций обязано принадлежать отрезку [-1, 1]. http://ideone.com/XjMJBa

Comment: Поправка. Для аргументов от 0 до PI

Comment: @iRumba, да, до PI.

Answer (score 1):

http://ideone.com/5X08MB

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Test
{
    private static double Convert(double a)
    {
        a %= 360;

        if (a < 0)
            a += 360;

        return a > 180 ? a - 360 : a;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        double[] a = { 0, 32, 70, 90, 150, 179, 180, 186, 190, 270, 350, 360, 400, -45, -90, -179, -180, -181, -270, -359, -360 };
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\n", a.Select(x => new { Original=x, Result=Convert(x) })));
    }
}
```

---

Одним выражением (хотя, это жуть) http://ideone.com/Rc4Mbo

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Test
{
    private static double Convert(double a)
    {
        return ((a + 360) % 360 + 360) % 360 - (int)(((a + 360) % 360 + 360) % 360 / 180 - 1e-12) * 360;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        double[] a = { 0, 32, 70, 90, 150, 179, 180, 186, 190, 270, 350, 360, 400, -45, -90, -179, -180, -181, -270, -359, -360 };
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\n", a.Select(x => new { Original=x, Result=Convert(x) })));
    }
}
```

Comment: Почти идеально. Но здесь присутствует два условия. А можно это как то записать формулой?

Comment: @iRumba, надо подумать. Но не считаю, что формула будет работать быстрее.

Comment: @iRumba, добавил способ с одним выражением.

Comment: Ну да, ни разу не быстрее :)